# Efectiveness of defenses against nunchaku and other flexible instruments

Tags: self-defense, krav-maga, nunchaku

Following this [demonstration](https://www.facebook.com/reel/782726937068354) and [this](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/10397/is-there-an-effective-way-to-defend-from-a-nunchaku) question. Is the demonstrated defenses (using the folded arms) effective against nunchaku and other flexible instruments such as belt?

Comment: The video you linked to doesn't work for me. Best to use a YouTube link instead of Facebook.